# What causes neural network accuracy to sharply increase after only one epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm using a relatively simple neural network with fully connected layers in keras. For some reason, the accuracy drastically increases basically to its final value after only one training epoch (likewise, the loss sharply decreases). I've tried architectures with larger and smaller numbers of hidden layers too. This network also performs poorly on the testing data, so I am trying to find a more optimal architecture or improve my training set accordingly.

It is trained on a set of 6500 1D array-like data, and I'm using a batch size of 512.

[image]

Comment: Can't say much without knowing more of your problem and how you managed your data. But that low accuracy in validation set could mean that you probably have to few samples in it.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Murilo, hard to say much without more information but it can come from multiple things:

- Your network learns through the batches of each epoch, meaning that
  your ~12 batches (6500/512) are already enough to learn a good bit of
  classification.
- Your weights are not really well initialized, and produce a huge
  loss for the first epoch. The massive decrease in the loss is
  actually the solver 'squishing' the weights. The best explanation I
  found for this comes from A. Karpathy in his 'MakeMore' tutorial:
  https://youtu.be/P6sfmUTpUmc?t=260

Now this sudden decrease of the loss is not extreme here (from 0.5 to 0.2) so I would not care much. I agree with Murilo that low accuracy in validation can come from too few samples in your validation set, or a bad shuffling between train and validation sets.